# Startup Password placed on Laptop by Hacker

Tags: windows-7, windows-8, security, passwords

I work in IT at a company and a member of staff has recently been hacked and the hacker has added the Startup Password authentication for Windows, I cannot guess the password and it is not the same as the account on the laptops password.

I have tried opening up Safe Mode and System Restore through the Startup Repair Screen but when I go to do so it tells me that because there isn't an Admin account I cannot do either of these functions.

I am presuming that this is because when the laptop was initially set up whoever set it up didn't create any kind of local account as they will have been prompted to use their Microsoft account.

I've tried creating a USB Drive with a iso for Windows 8 mounted to it but I think this startup password is blocking this too.

Also I cannot get access to the CD Tray as it seems to be a tray that can only be ejected through the OS as there's no buttons or pin hole for me to open it with a paper clip.

Does anyone know of any way I would be able to remove this? Any Suggestions will be warmly welcomed.

Comment: If its been compromised you should fully format and re-install. Who's to say its not been rootkitted and you arent handing it AD credentials.

Comment: Exactly what @Linef4ult says.  Wipe it and re-install.  If a hacker compromised a work laptop, you should assume that they just didn't put in a password and that is the end of it.  If they had access to the system that they could do that, then I look at that computer as a liability.  There's no telling what all they've done to this laptop.

Comment: @Linef4ult - fortunatly it wasn't a work laptop. The woman who gave laptop's son allowed for the hacker to connect via join.me and he phised for details and put this SysPass on. The laptop wouldn't boot from USB but managed to get the laptop re - formatted now using one of the advanced troubleshooting options I was offered.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try [Offline NT Password and Registry Editor](http://pogostick.net/%7Epnh/ntpasswd/)

Forgot your Windows admin password?

Reinstall? Oh no... But not any more...

Overview

This is a utility to reset the password of any user that has a valid local account on your Windows system.
Supports all Windows from NT3.5 to Win8.1, also 64 bit and also the Server versions (like 2003, 2008, 2012)
You do not need to know the old password to set a new one.
It works offline, that is, you have to shutdown your computer and boot off a CD or USB disk to do the password reset.
Will detect and offer to unlock locked or disabled out user accounts!
There is also a registry editor and other registry utilities that works under linux/unix, and can be used for other things than password editing.

How it is done?

Windows stores its user information, including crypted versions of the passwords, in a file called 'sam', usually found in \windows\system32\config. This file is a part of the registry, in a binary format previously undocumented, and not easily accessible. But thanks to a German(?) named B.D, I've now made a program that understands the registry.
This site provides CD and floppy images for end users to easily edit their forgotten passwords. But it also provides full source code and binary builds of the tools to allow others to use as they like for other purposes. Registry format documentation also available.

Source : [http://pogostick.net/~pnh/ntpasswd/](http://pogostick.net/%7Epnh/ntpasswd/)

Answer (score 0):

If you can amend the BIOS/EFI to boot from USB you could boot to a live version of Linux, wipe the drive and start again. That would seem like the only solution.

Then all you have to worry about is some rootkit that would do it all again. I'd proceed with caution!